# JSON single property formatting

Tags: c#, json

I have following JSON:

```
{
    "cap": [
      {  
         "type": "test"  
      },
      {  
         "type": "test1"  
      },
      {  
         "type": "test2",
         "bla": "tst"  
      }
    ]
}
```

I want every object that have single property to be one line formated

```
{  "type": "test"  }
```

so the final JSON should be

```
{
  "cap": [
    {  "type": "test"  },
    {  "type": "test1"  },
    {  
       "type": "test2",
       "bla": "tst"  
    }
  ]
}
```

How to do this in c#?

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957786/custom-json-string-output-using-newtonsoft

Comment: also "cap" should be in single line. Because . it's single property of root.