# Can I Use NewtonSoft JSON Serializer to convert a datset to an Array of Arrays instead of an Array of Objects?

Tags: json, datatables, json.net

The default output of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds2, Formatting.Indented)` is an array of objects.  I'd like to get an array of arrays with just the row data and not reapeating of the column name in each row.

I'd like to be able to present my recordset to DataTables as an array of columns and an array of row data items.  Getting the column names into a variable is pretty easy and fast, but I'm wondering what's the fastest way to get the row data into an array.

I'm not interested in compressing the data in transit as described in another answer.  The data needs to be processed on the client side in a jQuery `DataTable`.  The more rows returned the slower the JavaScript gets.

To be clear, I want the JSON Serializer to return data in the following format:

```
aoColumns: [
  "Name", 
  "Age", 
  "Location"
],
aaData: [
  ["Bob", 32, "Group1"],
  ["Sara", 43, "Group1"],
  ["Gary", 41, "Group2"]
]
```

`aaData` could be any name as `DataTables` can be told where to find the data and the column names.

Comment: You'd have to write your own [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) along the lines of the ones in [Custom JSON string output using Newtonsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957786) but with the added `aoColumns` property serialized.

Comment: I wound up using this article to solve my problem. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957786/custom-json-string-output-using-newtonsoft)