# Convert DataTable to JSON array

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Is there a way using NewtonSoft.Json or JavaScriptSerializer to serialize a DataTable as array of arrays instead of Array of objects. For example I need to serialize the datatable as below

```
[["Yellow", "Large", "Cotton"],["Red", "Medium", "Linen"]]
```

instead of

```
[{"Color":"Yellow", "Size":"Large", "Make":"Cotton"},{"Color":"Red", "Size":"Medium", "Make":"Linen"}]
```

Comment: Related though not quite identical: [Custom JSON string output using Newtonsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29957786/3744182).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataTable to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451460/datatable-to-json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.ItemArray));
```